How to fix ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns | beautifulSoup
I am getting an error:
ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns 

while scraping from wikipedia. See below. How do I fix this?
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

world_companies = soup.find('tr')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = world_companies)

column_data = table.find_all('tr')
for row in column_data[2:]:
    row_data = row.find_all('td')
    individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data]    
    length = len(df)
    df.loc[length] = individual_row_data


You don’t need beautifulsoup to scrap a table with pandas:
import pandas as pd

table_MN = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue')
for df in table_MN:
    if "Rank" in df.columns:
        print(df.to_string(index=False))

This table have two header rows. So if you skip the second row, it should work.

To fix the issue with BeautifulSoup try to iterate the elements in each <tr>:
world_companies = [e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.find('tr')]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = world_companies)

column_data = table.find_all('tr')
for row in column_data[2:]:
    individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row]
    length = len(df)
    df.loc[length] = individual_row_data

Would also recommend to scrape the table with pandas because you still loaded as modul and fix the column headers to your needs
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue')[0]
df.columns = [
    f"{col[0]}  {col[1]}" if col[0] != col[1] else col[0]
    for col in df.columns.values
]

print(df)




Rank
Name
Industry
Revenue  USD millions
Profit  USD millions
Employees
Headquarters[note 1]
State-owned
Ref.




1
Walmart
Retail
$648,125
$15,511
2100000
United States
nan
[1]


2
Amazon
Retail
$574,785
$30,425
1525000
United States
nan
[4]


...










49
Citigroup
Financials
$156,820
$9,228
237925
United States
nan
[52]


50
Centene Corporation
Healthcare
$153,999
$2,702
67700
United States
nan
[53]



